How to read an excel file with dynamic column name in Pentaho data integration?
I am new in Pentaho data Integration and I have a request to ingest and excel file with dynamic columns names. The columns names will be added or be deleted every month. We will need to load the data into a database table. We don't want to delete any database table field when column has been deleted in the Excel file but we want to add any new Excel column names.
For example we may have for

January column names : abc, cde, fgh, ijk

February column name: abc, cde, fgh, ijk, lmn -- HERE column name lmn has been added.

Mars column name: abc, cde, ijk, lmn, opq     -- HERE column name fgh has been deleted and opq    column has been added.


-- April column name: abc, cde, lmn, opq, rst   -- HERE column name ijk has been deleted and rst column has been added.
I tried meta data ingestion and also what is in this link https://www.closeit.co/post/dynamic-fields-in-pentaho-data-integration
but it did not works.
